# How to simplify a repeated STRUCT field from a column to another

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an array field in a table in this format (from an export from Datastore):

```
point   RECORD  REPEATED
point.x FLOAT   NULLABLE
point.y FLOAT   NULLABLE
point.key   RECORD  NULLABLE    
point.key.namespace STRING  NULLABLE    
point.key.app   STRING  NULLABLE    
point.key.path  STRING  NULLABLE    
point.key.kind  STRING  NULLABLE    
point.key.name  STRING  NULLABLE    
point.key.id    INTEGER NULLABLE
```

I want to copy this field from the table to another but in a simplified format. I only need to retain point.x and point.y:

```
point   RECORD  REPEATED
point.x FLOAT   NULLABLE
point.y FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this would work

```
select 
array(SELECT AS STRUCT x,y FROM UNNEST(point)) AS point
from ....
```